# Minimum element in a pair from 2 lists/arrays

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, min

I have 2 sorted integer lists or arrays `a` and `b`, both having same number of elements. I want to pair an element in `a` with an element in `b` such that when I take smaller element in all pairs, their sum is minimum.
For example,

```
a=[1,7,14,18]
b=[8,9,10,12]
```

I would be pairing `[(1,12),(7,10),(14,9),(18,8)]` and then taking smaller element in each pair, namely, `[1,7,9,8]`, I will get minimum sum. This is just one possibility I took. I want to know if this method of pairing elements of first list from the first element and moving forward with elements of the second list starting from end and going backwards will give me the minimum sum.

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Waqar *"I want to know if this method of pairing elements of first list from the first element and moving forward with elements of the second list starting from end and going backwards will give me the minimum sum."*

Comment: The [<algorithm>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) library has everything you need.

Comment: I removed the language specific tags since this is about an algorithm instead of an implementation.

Comment: for this example there are 24 possible pairings, so brute force checking all possible combinations should be possible

Comment: @idclev463035818 I dont want to perform brute force but I want to know if there is any possible algo for achieving this

Comment: @DewanshChhatri I know, but you didnt write that in your question. What you wrote is that you want to make sure that the solution you found is indeed the smallest solution, and that can be checked by using brute force

Comment: I don't understand completely. Which sum you want to be minimum , the sum of smaller elements from each pair? In that case you just sum up the first two values from each list, you don't even need to make pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that method of pairing the largest with the smallest will work:

1. If the largest element in the second array is smaller than the smallest in the first array, any pairing method will work and so pair the remaining elements using your method.
2. If not, pairing the first pair with your method will ensure the smallest from the first (which should be counted) will be counted and the largest from the second (which should not be counted) will not be counted
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 with the remaining elements from both arrays until you run out of elements

As you can see, the smallest remaining elements from the arrays will always be counted at each step along the way, and so the sum of the smallest from the resulting pairs will be minimized as desired.